# make canvas object to be draggable

Tags: javascript, canvas

In [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LuZbV/23/), house image to be draggable into container...i want canvas objects in toolbar to be draggable and droppable into container.how can i do this?please help me...

JS Code:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
var image1 = new Image();
image1.onload = function () {
   $house.show();
}
image1.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house32x32transparent.png";

$house.draggable({
   helper: 'clone',
});

$house.data("url", "house.png"); 
$house.data("width", "32"); 
$house.data("height", "33"); 
$house.data("image", image1); 
$stageContainer.droppable({
   drop: dragDrop,
});

function dragDrop(e, ui) {
    var x = parseInt(ui.offset.left - offsetX);
    var y = parseInt(ui.offset.top - offsetY);

    var element = ui.draggable;
    var data = element.data("url");
    var theImage = element.data("image");

    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
      name: data,
      x: x,
      y: y,
      image: theImage,
      draggable: true
  });
```

Comment: I'm confused...Your linked fiddle already does what you ask. :-/

Comment: @markE I'm asking canvas object like square,triangle to be drag gable. not image.....